# MATLAB GUI pop-up menu list get disappear when I set a default string?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

can somebody please tell me why my pop-up menu list get disappear when I set a string which actually belongs to one of the item in the list? I want this string to be appear as default when GUI gets open, however, want other items to be in the pop-up menu.

For example, pop-up list contains:

```
 Set_1
 Set_2
 Set_3
 Set_4 etc..
```

And, in the function **OpeningFcn**, I am settting:

```
 set(handles.popupmenu1, 'String', 'Set_1');
```

This makes 'Set_1' to appear when I open GUI. However, it makes other items (Set_2, Set_3 etc) disappear from the GUI. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `String` property of a popupmenu uicontrol sets the entire text that is displayed in the menu.

To select a particular option, set the `Value` property to the index of the item to be selected. In this case, since `Set_1` is the first item, set the `Value` property to 1.

Comment: I did something like: 
set(handles.popupmenu1, 'Value', 1);
set(handles.popupmenu1, 'String', 'Set_1'); but still it does not work. My list get disappear.

Comment: Like I said, if you set the `String` property to `Set_1`, it will set the entire text in the popupmenu to just `Set_1`. So don't do that. If you want to select the first item, just set the `Value` property to 1.